# When is $I - xA$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have a nonnegative real matrix $A$ for which all columns sum to 1 except for one which has all 0's. I need to show that $I - xA$ for some $x \in [0,1]$ is invertible.

I know that $I - B$ is invertible if the spectral radius $\rho(B) < 1$ exists and that the Perron-Frobenius theorem gives bounds for $\rho(B)$ for positive matrices: $\min_i \sum_j B_{ij} \le \rho(B) \le \max_j \sum_j B_{ij}$. However I don't know how to give bounds for non-negative matrices.

Comment: I think what he meant is that there exists $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $I-tA$ is invertible for all $t \in [0, x]$.

Comment: I am confused : For $0<x<1$, $I-xA$ is invertible if and only if $\frac{1}{x}I-A$ is invertible if and only if $\frac{1}{x}$ is NOT eigenvalue of $A$. Since every matrix can only have finte many eigenvalues, does not every matrix have the given property which has to be proven ?

Comment: @JackyChong Yes, that would make much more sense!

Comment: @Peter Yes, that looks like a possible good answer...

Comment: Thanks to all, sorry that I was unclear! What I meant is that I want to give the conditions for $x$ s.t. $I- xA$ is invertible. My understanding now would be that $\det (\lambda I-A)=0 \Leftrightarrow (\lambda I-A)v=0 \Leftrightarrow (I-\frac{1}{\lambda} A)v=0$ so $x \ne \frac{1}{\lambda}$. Would there be a way to show that $\rho (A) \le 1$ for a matrix with column sums $\le 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda$, then we see that
\begin{align}
(I-xA)v = (1-x\lambda)v
\end{align}
which means $v$ is also an eigenvector with eigenvalues $1-x\lambda$. Choose $x$ to be small.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $A$ is a nonnegative real square matrix for which all columns sum to $1$ or less, then you can use the [Gershogorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) and the fact that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues to show that $\rho(xA) \leq 1$ for $x \in [0,1].$